# Linking between c# and c++ code not working in 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, c++, com, tlb

I have code in C++ and C# which are linked through COM. C# is generating TLB and DLL which are included in C++.

C# TLB file is registered in my system. I have done all the coding in 32-bit machine. Now I have taken the same two programs on my 64 bit machine and building them. The builds are successful and the DLL/TLB files are getting generated. In 64 bit machine, by C++ code it is getting executed and giving the right result. But whenever the C# linking code snippet is encountered in my C++ code the code execution stops without throwing any error.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried building the c++ code in 64bit then build c# with the 64bit version of the dll's?

Comment: @StianStandahl Yeah I have build both the codes in 64 bit machine.

Comment: thats fine. But have you chosen 64x build configuration or is it any cpu? Because, when you have c++ references in c# code you have to build the c++ code with 64bit build configuration

Comment: i have selected 64x bit

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter where you build the program code. VS itself is 32-bit, and the compilers (`CSC.EXE`, `CL.EXE`) are 32-bit itself.

You'll need to ensure that on 64-bit machine, the C# program run is **matching** with the C++ platform. If you had used `AnyCPU` for C#, and 32-bit for C++, it simply won't run.

Ensure that C++ and C# code (at runtime) are targeting the same platform (runtime environment). A native (C++) binary (EXE/DLL) will remain 32-bit if it was built for 32-bit, and 64-64. A C# binary (IL) will get re-compiled into 32-bit or 64-bit as per the current OS. Confirm that.